# Installing etherpad-lite with docker-compose results in a folder not found exception

Tags: docker-compose, etherpad

This is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  etherpad:
    image: etherpad/etherpad:1.8.0
    ports:
      - "8001:9001"
    environment:
      - TITLE=Etherpad
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=root
      - USER_PASSWORD=demo
      - DB_TYPE=mysql
      - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_NAME=etherpad
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=mysql
      - DB_CHARSET=utf8
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - /home/etherpad-lite/data:/opt/etherpad-lite/var
```

The error message is [2023-12-27 08:41:01.792] [ERROR] console - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/etherpad-lite/var/minified_L2ph..
I am using a local database. How should I handle this issue?